# Rails Validation for Username and Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following validation rules for username and email.

```
validates :username,
    presence: {:message => "Please choose a username.", on: :update},
    uniqueness: {:message => "Username already exisits. Please select a different one."},
    length: {in: 3..15, :message => "Username should be 3-5 characters long", :allow_blank => true}

    validates :email,
      presence: {:message => "Please enter your Email Address."},
      uniqueness: {:message => "Email Address already exisits. Please Login!"}

    validate :email_regex
        def email_regex
            if email.present? and not email.match(/\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/)
                errors.add :email, "Please enter a valid Email Address."
        end
    end
```

For username: i do not want to allow anything other than - small letters, dot, numbers.

Do i need to write a completely different validate message like email_regex or is there a simplied version i can use appending my exisiting rules with a comma ','

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
validates :username, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i}
```

Add a comma separate option format to your existing validation for username. One more thing I missed, this is dummy regex, you need to apply as per your purpose.